# mongodb find all documents with common value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

How can I find all the documents with a common 'category'?

Below are my sample documents. How can get the documents that are common in categories?

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "59b7fcace893d0450c44ada3"
    },
    "title": "Tesla model 3 questions",
    "category": "movie",
    "questionAndAnswers": '',
    "__v": 0
}
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "59c4e12fd5276138f41c0896"
    },
    "title": "SpaceX Quiz",
    "category": "Science",
    "questionAndAnswers": '',
"__v": 0
}
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "59c4e12fd5276138f41c0890"
    },
    "title": "Nasa Quiz",
    "category": "Science",
    "questionAndAnswers": '',
"__v": 0
}
```

Comment: where category=='xxx'

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón thanks but it's returning only one of the documents :( 
This is what I have Quiz.find({category:'Science'},...

Comment: Just `$group` on `category`  to get all documents with same `category`. Something like `db.collection_name.aggregate({"$group":{"_id":"$category", "docs":{"$push":"$$ROOT"}}})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`db.collection.find({"category": "Science"})` will return a cursor, which you can iterate to get all the documents where "category" is "Science".

Check - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#find-documents-that-match-query-criteria

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried the below but no response in the page.
 
`app.get('/api/getRelatedData', function(req, res){

 Quiz.collection.find({"category": "Science"}, function(err, quiz) {
   if (err) throw err;

 // Quiz objects
   res.json(quiz[0]);
 });
});`

Comment: Quiz.find({"category": "Science"}... returns only one document and the Quiz is `var Quiz = mongoose.model('Quiz', quizSchema);`

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `where category == 'theCommonCategory'.`

It will give you all the documents that have theCommonCategory.

Comment: Sorry... I am looking for answers something like Quiz.find({category:'Science'},...